# Need Equivalent gatling scala code from postman curl url

Tags: scala, curl, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

Need Equivalent gatling scala code from postman curl url

could you please just logically write a equivalent gatling  scala code for below authentication request,first thing first is i need to get a auth request and its response using gatling scala .Below is the authentication curl request in PostMan which is working fine,i mean giving 201 response ,but i am getting 400 response in Gatling using git url [github](https://gist.github.com/DiegoRam/4377f97859cb9141ed37)

Generated from a curl request:

```
curl 'https://api.platform.com/auth/oauth/token' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: https://api-origin.cloud/dev/reservations-web/signin' -H 'Origin: https://api.origin.cloud' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' -H 'Authorization: Basic aWtyd3VnaDM4NzFnaHc4cmduN3E4M2c2c3I=' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' --data 'grant_type=password&username=abc.xyc1%40abc.com&password=Password1%21' --compressed
```

Below is the scala equivalent code i tried generating but getting 400 response

```
package simulations

import baseConfig.BaseSimulation
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.session
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.util.Random

class ogrebattledriverPostAccessToken extends BaseSimulation {



   exec(
      http("HTTP Request auth")
        .post("https://api.platform.com/auth/oauth/token")
        .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .formParam("grant_type","password")
        .formParam("username", "TableTopEng%40xxxs.com")
        .formParam("password", "actual password")
        .check(status is 200)
        .check(jsonPath("$.access_token").saveAs("access_token"))
        .check(jsonPath("$.token_type").saveAs("token_type"))
    )


  //val PostData=jsonFile("input-json.json").circular
  def name() = Random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE).toString



   //val headers_10 = Map("Content-Type" -> """application/json""","Authorization","${token_type} + ${access_token}" )


  def getSpecificOgreID()={
    repeat(140000){
      exec(flushHttpCache)

        feed(usersDataSource)
        .exec(http("PostRequestPerformanceTestingOgreBattleDriver")
          .post("https://api.tabletop-stage.tiamat-origin.cloud/dev/ogre-battledriver/Organizations")
         // .headers(headers_10)
          .header("Authorization", "${token_type} + ${access_token}")
          .body(StringBody(session =>
            s"""
               |{
               |  "name": "${name()}",
               |  "latitude": 66.256538,
               |  "longitude": -95.934502,
               |  "phoneNumber": "555-555-5555",
               |  "emailAddress": "perftest1@perftest1.com",
               |  "website": "https://perftest1",
               |  "streetLine1": "123 perftest1.",
               |  "streetLine2": "Ste 400",
               |  "city": "Omaha",
               |  "state": "NE",
               |  "zipCode": "98002"
               |}
          """.stripMargin)).asJSON

          .check(status.in(200,201))//checkforaspecificstatus
          .check(jsonPath(path="$.name").saveAs(key="name")))//checkforaspecificstatus
        .exec{session=>println(session);session}//parameterfortheorgIdgoeshere
        .pause(1)

    }
  }

  // add a scenario
  val scn = scenario("Battle Driver Get Orgs ")

    .forever() { // add in the forever() method - users now loop forever
      exec(getSpecificOgreID())
    }
```

Error i am getting in Intellij Editor

```
20:22:56.563 [ERROR] i.g.h.a.s.HttpRequestAction - 'httpRequest-5' failed to execute: No attribute named 'access_token' is defined
```

Can someone please write a logical gatling scala code from above postman curl request??

Comment: you need to extract the access token from the reply to the first call

Comment: that's what the problem is first call "HTTP Request auth" not able to generate access token,hence i am asking someone to help to rewrite curl command to scala code,curl is returning json response in postman,i want my scala code also to generate response like curl,but that is not happening

Comment: just for people interest,this got resolved by small tweak i.e. directly placed Url in gatling recorder and amended the script,got the access_key and bearer token